# How to show images/links on DIV hover?

Tags: css

How can I achieve the affect like here on SO when you hover over a comment:

- an arrow up to vote up
- a flag to mark that message
- if you are the comment author you get option to delete as well

How can I make links and images like that show when hovering over a DIV or even a table cell?

Comment: don't forget to consider the needs of mobile users. Hovering is not an option on many mobile browsers. Most notably Safari on iPhones, which has a completely different interaction model to the desktop version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
.comment .button {
   visibility: hidden;
}  

.comment:hover .button {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
  <a ...><img class="vote button" ...></a>
  <a ...><img class="flag button" ...></a>
  <a ...><img class="delete button" ...></a>
  <span class="comment-text">...</span>
</div>
```

---

[Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26210/andrew-moore) noted that this pure CSS solution won't work in IE6. And as [Noel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53030/noel-walters) pointed out, hovering just isn't an option in mobile browsers. You can use progressive enhancement to have the buttons always visible in those cases.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

.comment .button {
   visibility: hidden;   
}  

.comment:hover .button {
   visibility: visible;
} 

</style> 


<!--[if lt IE 7]>  
<style type="text/css"> 
.comment .button {
  visibility: visible; 
}   
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

IE6 will understand the first style, making the buttons hidden, but not the second, making them visible again on hover. The third style is in a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), which non-IE browsers and IE7+ will ignore. It overrides the first style, making the buttons visible always.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, it works greta in chrome but in firefox, it always shows the buttons, anyway to fix that?

Comment: What version of Firefox? Works for me on 3.5.2 / Mac.

Comment: weird I have the same version but on windows and it does not work for me on FF, I even tried putting your example on it's own page to verify no interference but still won't work =(

Comment: I have 3.0.11 in Windows, and it works there. A friend just verified it on 3.5.1/Win. Here's the complete file I'm using to test: http://pastie.textmate.org/578735

Answer (score 1):

```
div:hover {
    background-image:url('arrow.gif');
}
```

Comment: How would I make that link as well then?

Comment: Instead of using a <div>, you could use the CSS selector a:hover and set it's width, height, and background image.  You also would need to set display:block; on it, since <a> tags are normally inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

The key to what you are trying to do -- as I think the other answers are saying-- isn't to create the content on hover, but to make it "visible" on hover. It's always there, just not in a way the user can see or interact with. So you'd have something like:

```
 <div class="vote_arrow">
     <a ...>Clicking on me is fun</a>
 </div>
```

and then a CSS rule like:

```
 .vote_arrow a {
     display:none;
  }

  .vote_arrow:hover a {
      display: block;
  }
```

Be aware, though, that this method requires that the user have CSS turned on. Make your hidden content set up in such a way that if I have CSS off, the links still make some amount of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="special">
    <div class="links_holder">
        <a class="flag" title="Flag" href="flag.html">Flag</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Hello, this is my content!
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the following CSS to hide the links:

```
div.special div.links_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 16px; /* For a 16x16 link image */
    margin: 0 4px 0 0; padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

div.links_holder a.flag {
    display: block;
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Move the text out of the way 
       It's there for screen readers */
    text-indent: -9999px; 
    background: url('flag.gif') top left no-repeat;
}

div.special:hover div.links_holder {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Note that this will not work in IE6 since IE6 and below only supports the `:hover` pseudo-tag on `<a>` tags. In which case you'll need to revert back to a JavaScript solution. Example with MooTools:

```
$$('div.links_holder a.flag').each(function(el) {
    el.addEvents({
        'mouseenter': function() {
             el.addClass('hover');
         },
         'mouseleave': function() {
             el.removeClass('hover');
         }
    });
}, this);
```